# Ubuntu 11.04, adduser myuser: admin group is missing

Tags: ubuntu, users

Hi I'm trying to add myuser to sudoers after a fresh install with root account,

```
# adduser myuser admin
```

which gives:

```
adduser: the group `admin' does not exist.
```

however this works:

```
# adduser myuser root
```

but it doesn't make myuser a sudoer.

Furthermore, /etc/sudoers does contain these lines:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

but pretty strange -- the file **/etc/group doesn't** contain **admin**.

Should I just manually edit it and add something like:

```
admin:x:120:myuser
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `groupadd admin` to add the group then you could run `adduser myuser admin`.  However you may want to instead use `usermod -G myuser,admin myuser` to remove yourself from the root group. (instead of myuser,admin, list the exact list of groups your user should be a member of.

If you ever get tempted to edit /etc/group directly, please use the `vigr` command, which will make sure the syntax of the file is correct before committing changes.

Comment: Thanks @stew! worked like a magic! one thing i had to do is to logout and then login with myuser.

Answer (score 1):

the **sudo** group should be used:

```
adduser myuser sudo
```